# How to train two neural networks together

Tags: python, keras, cnn, convolutional-neural-network

This could be considered as an extension of my previous question "[How to make a region of interest proposal from convolutional feature maps?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/44391/how-to-make-a-region-of-interest-proposal-from-convolutional-feature-maps)".

## Network 1:

I have a multi-input neural network, it takes three types of inputs:

**Screenshot**: 1280x800 2D input shape.

**TextMaps**: 160x160x168 input shape.

**Candidates**: just bounding boxes of regions (not relevant in this case).

As displayed in the question above, this is the image of architecture:

[image]

And here's the code:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, ZeroPadding2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization, concatenate
from keras.activations import relu
from keras.initializers import RandomUniform, Constant, TruncatedNormal

#  Network 1, Layer 1
screenshot = Input(shape=(1280, 1280, 0),
                   dtype='float32',
                   name='screenshot')
# padded1 = ZeroPadding2D(padding=5, data_format=None)(screenshot)
conv1 = Conv2D(filters=96,
               kernel_size=11,
               strides=(4, 4),
               activation=relu,
               padding='same')(screenshot)
# conv1 = Conv2D(filters=96, kernel_size=11, strides=(4, 4), activation=relu, padding='same')(padded1)
pooling1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3),
                        strides=(2, 2),
                        padding='same')(conv1)
normalized1 = BatchNormalization()(pooling1)  # https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145768/importance-of-local-response-normalization-in-cnn

# Network 1, Layer 2

# padded2 = ZeroPadding2D(padding=2, data_format=None)(normalized1)
conv2 = Conv2D(filters=256,
               kernel_size=5,
               activation=relu,
               padding='same')(normalized1)
# conv2 = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=5, activation=relu, padding='same')(padded2)
normalized2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
# padded3 = ZeroPadding2D(padding=1, data_format=None)(normalized2)
conv3 = Conv2D(filters=384,
               kernel_size=3,
               activation=relu,
               padding='same',
               kernel_initializer=TruncatedNormal(stddev=0.01),
               bias_initializer=Constant(value=0.1))(normalized2)
# conv3 = Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=3, activation=relu, padding='same',
#               kernel_initializer=RandomUniform(stddev=0.1),
#               bias_initializer=Constant(value=0.1))(padded3)

# Network 2, Layer 1

textmaps = Input(shape=(160, 160, 128),
                 dtype='float32',
                 name='textmaps')
txt_conv1 = Conv2D(filters=48,
                   kernel_size=1,
                   activation=relu,
                   padding='same',
                   kernel_initializer=TruncatedNormal(stddev=0.01),
                   bias_initializer=Constant(value=0.1))(textmaps)

# (Network 1 + Network 2), Layer 1

merged = concatenate([conv3, txt_conv1], axis=-1)
merged_padding = ZeroPadding2D(padding=2, data_format=None)(merged)
merged_conv = Conv2D(filters=96,
                     kernel_size=5,
                     activation=relu, padding='same',
                     kernel_initializer=TruncatedNormal(stddev=0.01),
                     bias_initializer=Constant(value=0.1))(merged_padding)
```

## Problem:

Before I go to a **Network 2**, I'll already present a problem.

As you see in the image above, at the end of the architecture we have a **ROI MaxPool layer**. I use a [method used presented by Faster R-CNN](https://towardsdatascience.com/faster-r-cnn-object-detection-implemented-by-keras-for-custom-data-from-googles-open-images-125f62b9141a), which is based on region proposal networks that should be trained alone. Let's refer to region proposal network as **Network 2**.

But here's the problem, in order to train my **Network 1**, I need to train **Network 2**, but in order to train **Network 2**, I need to train a **Network 1**.

Is there any way to get beyond this problem?

P. S

**Network 2** is nothing more than a network that has [2 convolutional and 1 linear layers](https://github.com/yhenon/keras-frcnn/blob/master/keras_frcnn/vgg.py#L88), and it is based on feature maps given by **Network 1**. [But it must be converted to region proposals by a special function](https://github.com/yhenon/keras-frcnn/blob/6e5621cc51c9117d6a23ef7d6fbeba47dd009988/keras_frcnn/roi_helpers.py#L223), hence it must be evaluated during the training (but I can't just pass an empty shape information, it requires an actual feature map).

If there's any way to get around this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check merge functionality in Keras?

Comment: @Aditya I've used concatenate layer at the end. Did you mean keras.layers.Add? If so how can I use it for this purpose?